# <SharePoint:ThemedForegroundImage control doesn't work in non-master aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-addin, theme

Does anyone have any idea about SharePoint:ThemedForegroundImage web control?

It gives the correct themed image when used on Default.aspx which is using Master page.

But If I use it inside ClientWebPart.aspx which is not using any master page, it just renders default image.

Here is the code snippet I am using -

```
<a href="javascript:AddItem()" title="Add Item">
     <span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20 ms-heroCommandLink ms-hero-command-enabled-alt">
         <SharePoint:ThemedForegroundImage ThemeKey="spcommon" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png" runat="server" CssClass="ms-list-addnew-img20" ID="ThemedForegroundImage1" />
     </span>
     <span>add item</span>
</a>
```

Please help if someone has any idea or how to achieve this simple task. I am developing against SharePoint Online.

Thanks in advance.

-Jitender